# CSS - Can't call element in css if element is used for event function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input and a checkbox looking like this:

html:

```
<input class="form-control input_box" id="passwordRegister" name="password" type="text">

<div class="aweCheckbox aweCheckbox-primary">
    <input id="showPasswordRegister" type="checkbox">
    <label class="labelShowPasswordRegister input_title" for="showPasswordRegister">
    ::before
    Show password
    ::after
    </label>
</div>
```

I can style ::before of the label like this:

css:

```
.aweCheckbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  background-color: #337ab7;
  border-color: #337ab7;
}
```

All works fine. But if I add an ('event') function to the element

js:

```
function showPasswordRegister() {
    var x = document.getElementById("passwordRegister");
    if (x.type === "password") {
        x.type = "text";
    } else {
        x.type = "password";
    }
}   

$(".labelShowPasswordRegister").on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    showPasswordRegister();
});
```

... and in console I'm seeing:

```
<div class="aweCheckbox aweCheckbox-primary">
    <input id="showPasswordRegister" type="checkbox">
    <label class="labelShowPasswordRegister input_title" for="showPasswordRegister"> [Event]
    ::before
    Show password
    ::after
    </label>
</div>
```

... the styling of the label doesn' work. What am I missing?

Comment: Using `event.preventDefault()` in the event handler means that clicking on the label won't check the box. So the `:checked` modifier doesn't match.

Comment: @Barmar ... excelllent, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `event.preventDefault()` in the handler function. When you click on the label, this prevents the default action of triggering a click on the corresponding checkbox. The CSS matches the `:checked` pseudo-class, but you're not checking the box when you do this.

The CSS should still work if you click on the checkbox itself rather than the label.